# Sort django users with specific groups on the top

Tags: django, sorting, django-users, custom-sort

All users of the application are mapped to at least one group. Here is list of available groups:

```
>>>Group.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Group: superuser>, <Group: maintainer>, <Group: admin>, <Group: executive>, <Group: client>, <Group: other>]>
```

When I render all the users in the queryset with `.all()`, I want to sort them with a specific custom order such that, all the `Superusers` should be on the top, then `Admins`, then `Executives` and then rest of the Users as per below list.

```
custom_sort_order = ['superuser', 'admin', 'executive', 'client', 'maintainer', 'other']
```

Wondering, how can I use `sorted()` function on my `queryset`:

```
class UserList(generic.ListView):
    model = User
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    template_name = 'users/users.html' 
    paginate_by = 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort `user group name` by looking in to the `custom_sort_order`:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super().get_queryset() 
    custom_sort_order = ['superuser', 'admin', 'executive', 'client', 'maintainer', 'other']
    return sorted(qs, key=lambda item: custom_sort_order.index(item.groups.first().name))
```